# Getting the "Branch" Directory Name when using SVN in Teamcity

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Is there anything similar to `%teamcity.build.branch%` when using SVN? Or even the full URI for the checked out **SVN** directories?

I have a project setup as follows:

```
ProjectA
-- trunk/
-- release/
-- tags/
----build.x.x.x
```

The VCS Root is  `http://svnhost/svn/repo/ProjectA` and then I add Checkout Rules per build config -- e.g.  `+/trunk=>.`

Is there anyway to access the relative path, full url, etc to parse? For example, if this was a working directory, `svn info` would give the information I need.

Basically, I want to append part of the folder name to the version number, e.g. `#.#.#.#-trunk` or `#.#.#.#-release` or `#.#.#.#-tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a variable in the target, say "folder.name" and change the "VCS checkout rule" to

+:%folder.name% -> whatever

You can now use this variable folder name in your versioning and tagging operations as well

Comment: This is more or less what I ended up using.  Not as clean as branching when you use DVCS but seems like the only choice.